# Ubuntu 10.04 Puppet and Apache, apache service failing to start

Tags: ubuntu, apache2, puppet

Currently running a basic tutorial on configuring vm's with puppet to automate creating server environments

Currently I am running

```
puppet    3.1.0
apache2   2.2.14-5ubuntu Apache HTTP Server metapackage
```

I have a very basic init file to load apache2 and to make sure it is running.

```
package {
  "apache2":
  ensure => present
}
service {"apache2":
  ensure => true,
  enable => true,
}
```

When I try to run sudo puppet apply on this file i get the following error

```
Error: Could not start Service[apache2]: Execution of '/etc/init.d/apache2 start' returned 1: 
Error: /Stage[main]//Service[apache2]/ensure: change from stopped to running failed: Could not start Service[apache2]: Execution of '/etc/init.d/apache2 start' returned
```

What can I do to troubleshoot this issue?

Answer (score 4):

The package needs to be installed in order to start the service. So make it a requirement:

```
package { 'apache2':
  ensure => present,
}

service { 'apache2':
  ensure  => running,
  enable  => true,
  require => Package['apache2'],
}
```

If you still get an error, look at the server logs.

Comment: just to be explicit: the difference in this example is that the require parameter insures that the package is installed *before* the service is trying to start.  order in puppet is not necessarily enforced by the order in which resources are defined.